# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[f\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}\,\right)\right]^x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f''$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=1$ ,$f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=-1$ .

Then what is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[f\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}\,\right)\right]^x?$

When I was solving this problem, I supposed $f(x)$ to be a polynomial of degree two (because $f''$ is continuous) i.e. $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and found coefficients with the help of given values . I got $f(x)=\frac{-x^2}{2} +1$. After solving , I found limit to be $e^{-1}$. I know this is a particular case.

**Questions**

$1$ : Will the limit be same for all functions with these properties ?

$2$ : Please give me some method which works for all such $f(x)$.

$3$: I want to practice more questions of this kind, please give me some references i.e. books, problem books, any online source.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved easily by taking logarithm. Let $2/x=t^2$ so that $t\to 0^{+}$. If $L$ is the desired limit then by continuity of logarithm $\log L$ is equal to the limit of the expression $$x\log f\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}\right)=\frac{2}{t^2}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\log f(t)}{f(t)-1}}_{\to 1 } \cdot(f(t)-1)$$ which is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac{f(t)-f(0)-tf'(0)}{t^2/2}$$ which is equal to $f''(0)=-1$ via Taylor's theorem (or a single application of L'Hospital's Rule). Thus $L=1/e$. Note that we only need existence of $f''(0)$ and not its continuity.

---

For practicing limit problems (or any math problems) this site is the best. You can ask as well as answer questions here. For a brief discussion of techniques of evaluation of limits you may refer to my [blog series](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-1.html). As for books I always refer my favorite calculus book *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G H Hardy. It should be available online for free.

Comment: It means this limit will be same for all functions with these properties...?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: yes. You can see that I have not made any assumption about $f$ other than $f(0)=1,f'(0)=0,f''(0)=-1$. The limit is always $L=e^{f' '(0)}$.

Comment: I see , thanks a lot ! If you may answer my third question then I would be very grateful ,please!

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: I have given some references now.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\right)^{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\log\left(f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\log\left(f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)}\cdot f'\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}{-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)}\cdot f'\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f'\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)}{f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f''\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\cdot f\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)+\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\cdot f'\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{1+0}\\
&=-1.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you're almost there. Just need to get rid of the log, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer to your question and I'm not expecting any upvote, just to make it easier:

It seems for any polynomial with the degree equal or higher than $2$ this works fine: $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+1$

It satisfies all conditions required by the question:

$f(0)=1, f'(0)=0, f''(0)=-1$

We may assume there are lots of function that are with this form as this can be represented by **Taylor expansion** of other functions when $n \to \infty$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the limit is an indeterminate form $[1^\infty]$. Consider its logarithm
$$
x \log \left( f \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \right)\right),
$$
assuming that $f>0$. Now you should ask yourself how to expand the argument of the logarithm as $x \to +\infty$. Of course, you will need an expansion of $f$ near zero.

Then you can try to compare the logarithm with $x$, and hope to get a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

For $C^2$ functions, we have Taylor's theorem:
$$ f(h)^x = [ f(0) + f'(0)h + f''(0)h^2/2 + o(h^2) ]^x, \quad (h\to 0)$$
Plugging in values gives
\begin{align}
 f(\sqrt{2/x})^x 
&= \left[ 1 -x^{-1} + o(x^{-1})\right ]^x \\
&
= \left[ 1 -x^{-1} \right ]^x\frac{\left[ 1 -x^{-1} + o(x^{-1})\right ]^x}{\left[ 1 -x^{-1} \right ]^x}\\
&=\left[ 1 -x^{-1} \right ]^x\left[ 1 -o(x^{-1}) \right ]^x, \quad (x\to\infty)\end{align}
and  [$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-o(x^{-1}))^x = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572209/test-f-n-1-frac1n2n-for-convergence-and-give-its-limit-if-it-exists/2572365#2572365) so in the limit $x\to \infty$, the answer is $e^{-1}$. The linked proofs only show that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-x^{-2}))^x = 1$ but most if not all of the proofs should generalise.