# Calculate limit of $(1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^n$

Tags: limits

How to calculate

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n
$$

using only the very basic limit features (I cannot use the fact that it equals to $e^0 = 1$)?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "very basic limit features".

Comment: Can you use the estimates $$1\le (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n=\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}\right)^{1/n}\le e^{1/n}?$$

Comment: @Jakobian, well, using school math and sum, product, ... limit features

Comment: Use Bernoulli inequality to get $1-(1/n)\leq (1-(1/n^2))^n\leq 1$ and do the same for $(1-(1/n^4))^n$ and divide. This does not need any knowledge of $e$.

Comment: I don't attend your school, mind you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, post it as a solution, please

Comment: That's a nice idea @ParamanandSingh! Bernoulli is surely more basic than using $e$.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen see this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2572627/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, post this as answer, please

Comment: I think it is better to mark your question as duplicate. I don't want to copy paste same answer here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Bernoulli's inequality $$e^x\ge x+1\quad \text{for all }x\in\Bbb R$$

Therefore $$\left(1+n^{-2}\right)^n\le \left(e^{n^{-2}}\right)^n=e^{1/n}$$